# Handling emails in a separet email servers

Tags: domain-name-system, centos, nginx, vps, email-server

This is a problem about maintaining an all-email VPS server.
First, I have two VPS hosts right now, both running CentOS 6.5, 32bit system. one for web hosting and other for email only.

The reason for that is, since I have many sites, I want the web hosting environment to be completely isolated from the email.

So, I added A record for my domains in this order.

```
198.551.224.10     www.my-site.tld        # Pointing to my web host IP
198.551.224.10     my-site.tld            # Pointing to my web host IP
198.551.224.11     mail.my-site.tld       # Pointing to my mail host IP
```

The problem with this approach is that, every email created now will have a prefix of `mail` before it, like `joe@mai.my-site.tld` so, I was thinking of changing the above configuration to this:

```
   198.551.224.10     www.my-site.tld        # Pointing to my web host IP
   198.551.224.10     my-site.tld            # Pointing to my web host IP
   198.551.224.10     mail.my-site.tld       # Pointing to my mail host
```

This way, all addresses are pointing to the same IP, and then somehow tell nginx to redirect any information coming from server `mail.my-site.tld` to IP `198.551.224.11 (the EMAIL server)`

The problem is telling Nginx to redirect the request, yet if anyone has any better information about how to keep an separate email server while retaining that standard email format ex: `name@domain.tld`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `A` record will not impact your emails as long as you setup the correct `MX` record. If you want to receive emails for *@example.com*, you can setup your zone this way:

```
mail 3600 IN A 198.551.224.11
@ 3600 IN MX mail.example.com.
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but I don't have as much filed to type in the that setting. Here is a snap show of my config field http://i2.minus.com/j9O2eErEu4Qn3.jpg  and thanks for clarifying about the MX field.

Comment: @iOi For the MX record, you leave the zone empty and you put the name to your mail server in the value field.

Comment: Ok, I left zone empty, and added `mail` for the *value* field (first blank field). I am a little embarrassed to say though, what happens now? I am assuming this will redirect request to my mail server, and `user@domain.tld` will be able to read/accept emails?

Comment: When a mail server is sending a message, it looks for the `MX` record. In your case the reply will send them to ``mail.domain.tld` which what you want to achieve.

Comment: Thanks. I am assuming I have a lot of work to do from here, but I will try. Thunderbird does not seem to detect any account I created using the mail.domain.tld maybe it takes time for this record to propogate

Comment: @iOi If you want to retrieve emails using Thunderbird, you should setup an IMAP or POP3 server like Dovecot.

Comment: I have Dovecot installed, postfix and squirrelmail. I did EXACTLY as [This tutorial](http://www.unixmen.com/install-postfix-mail-server-with-dovecot-and-squirrelmail-on-centos-6-4/) I created two accounts, (joe@domain.tld & jane@domain.tld) I am able to send and receive emails between joe and jane, and I can send emails from them to yahoo and gmail, but I can't receive emails receive emails sent from gmail/yahoo to joe and jane. What do you think the problem is?

Comment: Can you pls take a look at this question? http://serverfault.com/questions/589953/postfix-sending-and-receiving-in-strange-way

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the MX settings, you may also need to configure your mail server to use your my-site.tld as its default domain. If using Postfix then look at the mydomain setting and the ones around it. CentOS comments the file good for that stuff.

Comment: Thanks @GeneBean, I that may be my current problem. I have mentioned [it here](http://serverfault.com/questions/589934/handling-emails-in-a-separet-email-servers/589935?noredirect=1#comment695431_589935) I can't upvote your question since I am low rep, and got suspended after asking that question weird enough. I will try to ask more detailed question with my old account if possible and ping you in

Comment: can you take a look at this question http://serverfault.com/questions/589953/postfix-sending-and-receiving-in-strange-way