# Postfix sending and receiving in strange way.

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, centos, postfix, email-server

I have an email server, running on CentOS 6.5, 32bit system, with Postfix and Dovecot running along all their dependencies. Let's assume my domain is www.anw.com

I have created `A` record in this order for my domain

```
    www.anw.com         37.143.374.15    # points to my web server
    anw.com             37.143.374.15    # points to my web server
    mail.anw.com        227.80.74.199    # points to my mail server
```

I have also created an `MX` server

```
   mail.anw.com    227.80.74.199
```

Now, using postfix I have created two accounts, namely `joe@anw.com` and `jane@anw.com`
using squirrelmail I can send and receive between those accounts without any problem. I can also send emails to any email account like Yahoo and Google, but I can't receive emails sent from Google or Yahoo.

Comment: Post the output of `netstat -lpn` and your postfix configuration file.

Comment: @Spack http://pastebin.com/mT9RmXjK BTW: [This is how](http://www.unixmen.com/install-postfix-mail-server-with-dovecot-and-squirrelmail-on-centos-6-4/) I set up my email server

Comment: I miss the important part. Try `netstat -ltpn` instead. And also the content of `/etc/postfix/main.cf`. If not too big, just put it in your question.

Comment: @Spack No problem. Here is [netstat ltpn](http://pastebin.com/x16NXvwJ) and [main.cf](http://pastebin.com/mcDHxQ4d)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your /etc/postfix/main.cf look at the following settings and the associated comments:

myhostname (your mail server's host name) 
mydomain = dailytech24.com  (you domain name) 
myorigin = $mydomain 
inet_interfaces = all  (if you only have IPv4 then this needs to change) 
mydestination 
mynetworks

Comment: You can check my settings in the comment, because I have done all what you have written before. I did exactly mentioned [in this tutorial](http://www.unixmen.com/install-postfix-mail-server-with-dovecot-and-squirrelmail-on-centos-6-4/)

Comment: @ANW post the output of postconf ¦grep -i my please

Comment: I tried your approach, it gives me an error saying 
`postconf: warning: ?:    unknown parameter 

postconf: warning: grep: unknown parameter

postconf: warning: -i: unknown parameter

postconf: warning: my: unknown parameter`

Comment: There is a pipe between postconf & grep

Comment: You should've given me | instead of ¦ :) 
Here is the pastbin http://pastebin.com/jGrLWMLG

Comment: why are myhostname & mydomain set to the same thing? When you do an MX lookup via something like mxtoolbox.com does this host and only this host show up?

Comment: Yes I think so. Here is the screen shot http://oi57.tinypic.com/x5cq9z.jpg

Comment: I am sure myhostname and mydomain should not point to the same thing as you said it, but the domain points (has to point to the web host server) because I have 2 VPS hosts, one for mail and other for web hosting

Comment: I tried STMP test, and it failed. I think the problem might be from that. But dovecot is working just fine. This is strange.

Comment: Mydomain needs to be what you want after the @ in your address. This will not effect your web server

Comment: Well, in that case it must be correctly configured. Don't you think? Because I am trying to receive emails in that order. name@domain.tld

Comment: If mydomain is right you need to adjust myhostname to something else then. I think you need to open up the networks that are allowed to use your server but be careful not to make it on "open relay". You'll need to do some kind of SMTP auth. The networks setting is why your SMTP test failed (most likely anyhow)

Comment: This does not help at all. I will accept the answer, since its unlikely to get anymore attention.

Comment: You may want to take a look at https://library.linode.com/mailserver to see if you can find where in the big picture overall process there is a hiccup. There is a link in the software section of the guide to a Postfix, Dovecot, & MySQL setup too. The guide I linked covers all the different types of DNS records that are needed too along with explanations of them.

Comment: Eventually I will. I just needed to solve this problem asap, because I've made 5 people pissed right now.

Comment: I think I've found the problem. [this guy had his problem fixed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15216412/postfix-not-able-to-receive-mails-from-external-domains) but I can't find that setting in my `main.cf` do you have any clue?

Answer (score 1):

Your Postfix is listening only on the Loopback interface (`127.0.0.1`). Edit the `/etc/postfx/main.cf` file and update the `inet_interfaces` parameters with your public IP address.

```
inet_interfaces = MY.IP.AD.DR,127.0.0.1
```

You will then have to restart the Postfix service.

```
# service postfix restart
```

Comment: Sorry my WiFi maxed out yesterday, but I tried it just now, and no result. Just so you know, there was inet_interface in main.cf. It was like this: `inet_interfaces = all` I am here if you want to ask me any more questions, and thanks so far @Spack